# How to add markers for 9000+ coordinates on a map efficiently? (from CSV file)

Tags: excel, csv, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have 9000 coordinates I need to mark on a map. Will this slow my map down and what way would you suggest I go about doing it?

The data is currently stored in a CSV file with 2 columns, latitude and longitude. If necessary the file format can be changed (I produced it in Excel).

Thanks

Comment: Use something like the markerclusterer plugin http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Comment: See this article in the documentation - [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)